# Maven dependency not found when building ODE source

Tags: java, maven, buildr, apache-ode, xdoclet

I have been trying to build the source code of `apache-ode` and it has a dependency for `xdoclet` in `pom.xml`. I am using `jruby` and `buildr` for building the code but `buildr` fails to download this dependency from any of the repositories listed in the `repositories.rb` file. Here is how the dependency looks like in `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xdoclet-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xdoclet</groupId>
            <artifactId>xjavadoc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-j5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Below is the list of repositories, `buildr` searches for the required packages

```
repositories.remote << "http://www.intalio.org/public/maven2"
repositories.remote << "http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-incubating-repository"
repositories.remote << "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
repositories.remote << "http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository"
repositories.remote << "http://download.java.net/maven/2"
repositories.remote << "http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/m2-repo"
repositories.remote << "http://www.aqute.biz/repo"
```

Any suggestions on how to fulfil the required dependency? Any repository that you know of? I am very new to `maven` and `buildr` and don't know where to look for and what is the format of the repository URL to provide

Comment: I don't see a version 1.1-j5 in Central, just 1.1.

Comment: yes, I can't find it either

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad, find my responses on the mailing list [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/ea1fb3393a08a8aa964b756dc93579e08395d7f471d94795bc4e65fa@%3Cuser.ode.apache.org%3E).
Apahce ODE uses Builr and not Maven. So don't go into the pom.xml